# Smartsheet Data Tracker: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-1.1

I am new to Python and I'm working with Smartsheet Data Tracker to update a sheet from a CSV file.

I have problems about the array list management in Python; I don't know about this error, I was reading about this error on StackOverflow but I don't understand it:

The error:

```
"File "C:\Users\David\DataTraker\connectors\CSVCon.py", line 61, in __init__     
    self.csvData.append(readerRow)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'"
```

And my code:

```
def __init__(self, sourceConfig):
    self.csvData = []


    self.csvData = {"sourceId": "siniestros",
                    "connectorClassName": "CSVCon",
                    "fileName": "siniestros.csv",
                    "isStrict": False}

    for readerRow in sourceReader:
        self.csvData.append(readerRow)
```

Comment: You can only `append` to a `list`.

Answer (score 2):

What is going wrong is that you create a `list` to which you would like to `append` later. However you overwrite that afterwards with a dictionary, to which you cannot append. This is why you get an `AttributeError`.

---

To fix this, I would rename your dictionary (`self.csvData={stuff}`) that you created after your `list` to something else such as `self.meta`, perhaps. Alternatively, you could rename your `list`.

It doesn't matter which, you just need to remove the naming conflict so both variables can co-exist in the namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this was more an issue of poorly commented code in the [Data Tracker](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/Smartsheet-Data-Tracker) project that caused the confusion in the [CSVCon.py](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/Smartsheet-Data-Tracker/blob/master/dataTracker/connectors/CSVCon.py) file. The CSV Configuration settings that are in those comments are an example of what should be in the `settings/sources.json` file.

The [Configure Source](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/Smartsheet-Data-Tracker#configure-source) section in the project documentation provides some more detail on setting up your source in the [sources.json](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/Smartsheet-Data-Tracker/blob/master/dataTracker/settings/sources.json) file.

There is also a [section](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/Smartsheet-Data-Tracker#csv) with an explanation of the [CSV source](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/Smartsheet-Data-Tracker#csv) specifically.

The confusing commenting has been updated to be more clear.