# Arff Loader : AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: python, attributes, runtime-error, arff

I am trying to load a .arff file into a numpy array using liac-arff library. (https://github.com/renatopp/liac-arff)

This is my code.

```
import arff, numpy as np
dataset = arff.load(open('mydataset.arff', 'rb'))
data = np.array(dataset.data)
```

when executing, I am getting the error.

```
ArffLoader.py", line 8, in <module>
data = np.array(dataset.data)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'data'
```

I have seen similar threads, [Smartsheet Data Tracker: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23016559/smartsheet-data-tracker-attributeerror-dict-object-has-no-attribute-append). I am new to Python and is not able to resolve this issue. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Short version

`dataset` is a `dict`.  For a `dict`, you access the values using the python indexing notation, `dataset[key]`, where `key` could be a string, integer, float, tuple, or any other immutable data type (it is a bit more complicated than that, more below if you are interested).

In your case, the key is in the form of a string.  To access it, you need to give the string you want as an index, like so:

```
import arff
import numpy as np
dataset = arff.load(open('mydataset.arff', 'rb'))
data = np.array(dataset['data'])
```

(you also shouldn't put the imports on the same line, although this is just a readability issue)

### More detailed explanation

`dataset` is a `dict`, which on some languages is called a `map` or `hashtable`.   In a `dict`, you access values in a similar way to how you index in a list or array, except the "index" can be any data-type that is "hashable" (which is, ideally, unique identifier for each possible value).  This "index" is called a "key".  In practice, at least for built-in types and most major packages, only immutable data types or hashable, but there is no actual rule that requires this to be the case.

Do you come from `MATLAB`?  If so, then you are probably trying to use `MATLAB's` `struct` access technique.  You could think of a `dict` as a much faster, more flexible `struct`, but syntax for accessing values are is different.

Comment: Thanks, this is working. My programming background is mainly Java and I have just started in Python. The code, I used is from here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27264426/arff-files-with-scikit-learn.

Comment: @Erdnase just edited my answer in the refered question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Its easy to load arff data into python using scipy.

```
from scipy.io import arff

import pandas as pd

data = arff.loadarff('dataset.arff')

df = pd.DataFrame(data[0])

df.head()
```